# swift and c++ function with pointers

Tags: c++, swift

I have to use big C++ file in project. In this file there class Detect with public function

```
void processFrame_new(const unsigned char *frame_i, int width_i, int height_i,
                      uint timestamp, int &state, int &index, int &x, int &y,
                      int &debug);
```

as I understand I can get result from this function through pointers state, index, x, y, debug.
Calculation in this function take time, so get result is async issue. How I can call this function and get results?

PS Thanks to rob mayoff now I understand how to wrap C++ code. Last question "How can I observe change of WrapperReturnValue if calculation inside processFrame_new(...) take some time?"

Comment: If you do have a new question pls post it, we try too keep one question p/ post

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call a C++ interface directly from Swift, because the importer only understands C and Objective-C, not C++. So you need to write a wrapper with a strictly C or Objective-C interface.

For example, you can declare a C wrapper function in a header file like this:

```
// wrapper.h

#ifndef wrapper_h
#define wrapper_h

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct {
    int state;
    int index;
    int x;
    int y;
    int debug;
} WrapperReturnValue;

WrapperReturnValue wrapped_processFrame_new(const unsigned char *frame, int width, int height, unsigned int timestamp);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* wrapper_hpp */
```

In your bridging header, you can import `wrapper.h` to make `WrapperReturnValue` and `wrapped_processFrame_new` available to Swift:

```
// test-Bridging-Header.h

//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//

#import "wrapper.h"
```

You can then implement the wrapper function in C++, like this:

```
// wrapper.cpp

#include "wrapper.h"

void processFrame_new(const unsigned char *frame_i, int width_i, int height_i,
                      unsigned int timestamp, int &state, int &index, int &x, int &y,
                      int &debug);

WrapperReturnValue wrapped_processFrame_new(const unsigned char *frame, int width, int height, unsigned int timestamp) {
    WrapperReturnValue r = {};
    processFrame_new(frame, width, height, timestamp, r.state, r.index, r.x, r.y, r.debug);
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help.How can I observe change of WrapperReturnValue if calculation inside processFrame_new(...) take some time?