# Use openCV in C++ and in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

In my Swift project I use some C++ code, that use openCV framework. So I create Objective-C wrapper and it's works ok. Then I want to use some openCV functionality directly from swift. I add

```
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

to "Bridging-Header.h" and get bunch of error "Core.hpp header must be compiled as C++" from C++ code. Is there any way to work with OpenCV in C++ code and in Swift code in the same project?

Comment: You *cannot* import C++ headers to Swift (as was pointed out to you at https://stackoverflow.com/a/49451486). Using a wrapper is the only approach.

Comment: See also [Interacting with C++ classes from Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35229149/interacting-with-c-classes-from-swift)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [swift and c++ function with pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49451133/swift-and-c-function-with-pointers)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to use C++ headers inside bridging header file. 
Wrap all C++ code by h/mm files

Answer (score 0):

1. integrate OpenCV using pod instead of integrating the library directly.
2. Create the .pch file and import.

   ```
   #ifndef PrefixHeader_pch
   #define PrefixHeader_pch
   #ifdef __cplusplus
   #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
   #endif
   #endif /* PrefixHeader_pch */
   ```
3. Create the Wrapper file in Objective C file .h and .m and rename the .m to .mm

   **Write all logic part in the wrapper file**
4. Create a bridging header file and import the Wrapper file into it.

   ```
   #import "OpenCVWrapperr.h"
   ```